# Linux C++ linking with two versions of static libraries

Tags: c++, linux, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I'm building a python extension library. Unfortunately, I'm forced to use different versions of a static library (libtiff). To avoid binding conflicts, I separated all calls to different versions of the static library in different shared "so" libraries.
[image]

I used fvisibility "hidden" flag for compiling of the "so" libraries to hide the implementations of versions of the static libraries.
Unfortunately,it does not work. My process is crashing because A.so calls some of the functions from C(2).a.
I tried to set env variable LD_BIND_NOW to reduce lazy binding effects. It did not help.

I'm using **CentOS-7**, **cmake**, **gcc** v. 10.2.1, **ld** v. 2.35-5.el7.4
Is there any way to isolate the static libraries? Any comment will be appreciated.

It works perfectly for Windows. Looks ok for OSX and the latest version of Ubuntu. Unfortunately, I have to build the library with "manylinux" Linux based on CentOS-7 to be able to distribute my python library on different Linux platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that setting  "fvisibility" flag to "hidden" for a library hides not only library classes/functions, but as well classes/functions from child libraries. It is wrong. The flag has no effect on child libraries. They remain visible to the linker.
Fortunately, there is a flag that hides only child library APIs.
In CMake file, it looks so

```
if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--exclude-libs,${LIB}")
endif()
```

Comment: I can't find `HIDE_PRIVATE_SYMBOLS` in CMake document. Is it an user defined variable?

Comment: You're right, it is a user defined variable. I removed it from the code snippet to avoid confusion. Thanks!